# Echo an array value from file.php to webpage.php

Tags: php, arrays, include

I have a simple array that stores various maths examples and I have saved this in webpage.php, the aim of the array is to generate a random example each time a webpage is loaded.  For this I have used the rand function in PHP:

```
$Examples = array();

$Examples[0] = "Maths example 1";
$Examples[1] = "Maths example 2";
$Examples[2] = "Maths example 3";
$Examples[3] = "Maths example 4";

$index = rand(0, count($Examples));
echo $Examples[$index];
```

so this basically calls and prints a random example each time the page is loaded.  What I want to do is to save this array in file.php not webpage.php whilst maintaining the functionality of the code.
So basically only keeping

```
echo $Examples[$index];
```

within the webpage rather than writing to the array within the webpage.

I have thought about

```
<?php include ('file.php'); ?>
```

within the webpage and then echoing it as above, but as a beginner I am not to sure about the syntax or wrongs and rights of doing this.  Please help if you can.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried/executed the code?

Comment: Because you will end up with many of these types of functions, create a file called `functions.php`, make that *Example* code a function, and then call it on whatever page you need it.  You'll still need to `require_once('functions.php')` (instead of `include`...for reasons best in another question), but then all your functions will be in a single include rather than pollute your file with a lot of includes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `functions` to create re-utilizable code:

```
// file.php
function getMathExamples()
{
    $Examples = array();

    $Examples[0] = "Maths example 1";
    $Examples[1] = "Maths example 2";
    $Examples[2] = "Maths example 3";
    $Examples[3] = "Maths example 4";

    $index = rand(0, count($Examples)-1);

    return $Examples[$index];
}
```

And then use it in any page:

```
// webpage.php (or wherever you need to echo math examples)
require("file.php");

echo getMathExamples();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could separate the storage from the logic like following :

First step is to create a storage file that will handle the examples. You also could rename `file.php` into something more explicit, like `math_examples.php` which contains :

```
<?php
    return [
        'Math example 1',
        'Math example 2',
        'Math example 3'
    ];
?>`
```

Next, you want to get this into an array in your logic code. Do like following in your `webpage.php` :

```
<?php
    $math_examples = require('file.php'); // or 'math_examples.php'
?>
```

Then, you can apply the logic here. What contains `$math_examples` is your array of examples ! So you may play with it like following :

```
<?php
    $math_examples = require('file.php'); // or 'math_examples.php'

    $examples_count = count($math_examples);

    $randomNumber = rand(0, $examples_count - 1); // Beware of the inclusion of the max !

    $randomExample = $math_examples[$randomNumber];

    echo $randomExample;
?>
```

Comment: This is also very helpful thank you very much, a good way of organizing the code!